# Bootstrap Collapse is not working with dust

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, express, dust.js

I am very new to express js and bootstrap. 
I am using Dust view engine. Everything was working fine except the collapse functionality.It is not working.
My layout.dust file include jquery and bootstrap -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/stylesheets/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container" >
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-offset-2 col-md-7">
                {+body /}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "/javascripts/bootstrap.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get a collapse effect in my index.dust for clicking on button but unfortunately it is not working

```
{> "layout"/}
{<body}
   {#models}
    <div class = "well">
        <h4>{Name} <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#models_{Name}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="models_{Name}">View</button></h4>
        <div class="collapse" id="models_{Name}">
            TREST
        </div>

    </div>
   {/models}
   {/body}
```

could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this I think you might be missing the href attribute?

have you tried?:

```
{> "layout"/}
{<body}
   {#models}
    <div class = "well">
        <h4>{Name} <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#models_{Name}" href="#models_{Name}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="models_{Name}">View</button></h4>
        <div class="collapse" id="models_{Name}">
            TREST
        </div>

    </div>
   {/models}
   {/body}
```